# How to setup SSL in Zeppelin

Tags: ssl, jetty, apache-zeppelin

I'm trying to setup SSL in Zeppelin and after following the [instructions](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0/install/configuration.html) and all related Google searches, the zeppelin service status says it's ok but the web response is `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

These are the parts of the zeppelin-site.xml I modified

```
<property>
  <name>zeppelin.ssl</name>
  <value>true</value>
  <description>Should SSL be used by the servers?</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>zeppelin.ssl.client.auth</name>
  <value>false</value>
  <description>Should client authentication be used for SSL connections?</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>zeppelin.ssl.keystore.path</name>
  <value>/opt/zeppelin/lib/keystore</value>
  <description>Path to keystore relative to Zeppelin configuration directory</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>zeppelin.ssl.keystore.type</name>
  <value>JKS</value>
  <description>The format of the given keystore (e.g. JKS or PKCS12)</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>zeppelin.ssl.keystore.password</name>
  <value><super secret password></value>
  <description>Keystore password. Can be obfuscated by the Jetty Password tool</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>zeppelin.ssl.truststore.path</name>
  <value>/opt/zeppelin/lib/keystore</value>
  <description>Path to truststore relative to Zeppelin configuration directory. Defaults to the keystore path</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>zeppelin.ssl.truststore.type</name>
  <value>JKS</value>
  <description>The format of the given truststore (e.g. JKS or PKCS12). Defaults to the same type as the keystore type</description>
</property>
```

Then this is the service status, which says I'm running but in actuality the web page returns an error:

```
● zeppelin.service - Zeppelin service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/zeppelin.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-05-09 18:26:41 UTC; 28s ago
  Process: 347 ExecStop=/opt/zeppelin/bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 413 ExecStart=/opt/zeppelin/bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 441 (java)
    Tasks: 39 (limit: 4662)
   CGroup: /system.slice/zeppelin.service
           └─441 java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///opt/zeppelin/conf/log4j.properties -Dzeppelin.log.file=/opt/zeppelin/logs/zeppelin-zeppelin-myserver.log -cp ::/op
```

Comment: do you have any information from the request log?

Comment: I've checked in the `{zeppelin}/logs/*` for the `.log` and `.out` files and nothing there to indicate anything wrong. Are there other logs to go looking in for help?

Comment: which os have you installed this on could you run the equivalent of systemctl status zeppelin.service?

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu. I'll update my main post with the service status and my zeppelin-site.xml

Answer (score 0):

You should set zeppelin.ssl property to true :

```
<property>
   <name>zeppelin.ssl</name>
   <value>true</value>
   <description>Should SSL be used by the servers?</description>
</property>
```

Comment: My mistake when copying to the post. I have been setting it to true. When I do the site goes unresponsive.